# TableView doesn't reload itself once adding a value into an array in Swift

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

been searching for an answer across the website but couldn't find something so hope to get an answer :).

Well my problem is (for some reason even tho I've done this many times) every time I add a value(task) into my array for some reason my tableView doesn't reload itself and for seeing my items into the array, I need to go back and just let the ViewWillAppear do it's job..

basically what I'm trying to do is - I got 2 arrays of TasksArray and DoneArray, every time I add a value I insert it into TasksArray, after the user selects the "Done" button, I insert the task into DoneArray.

Here's my Code:

```
import Foundation
import CoreData
import UIKit
import SwipeCellKit

class TasksManViewController: UITableViewController, SwipeTableViewCellDelegate {
    
    
    
    @IBOutlet weak var Sege: UISegmentedControl!
    
    let isSwipeRightEnabled = true
    
    
    var tasksArray = [Task](){
        didSet {
            // because we perform this operation on the main thread, it is safe
            DispatchQueue.main.async {
                self.tableView.reloadData()
            }
        }
    }
    
    var doneTasksArr = [Task]() // an array of what to disply.
    
    lazy var rowsToDisply = tasksArray 
    
    let context = (UIApplication.shared.delegate as! AppDelegate).persistentContainer.viewContext
    
    
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        
    }
    
    
    override func viewWillAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
        loadTasks()
        tableView.reloadData()
    }

    
    
    // MARK: - DataSource + Delegate Methods:
    override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return rowsToDisply.count
    }
    
    
    override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "taskCellRow") as! SwipeTableViewCell
        cell.delegate = self
        
        cell.textLabel?.text = rowsToDisply[indexPath.row].title
        return cell
    }
    
    
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, editActionsForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath, for orientation: SwipeActionsOrientation) -> [SwipeAction]? {
        if orientation == .left {
            guard isSwipeRightEnabled else { return nil }
            let doneAction = SwipeAction(style: .destructive, title: "Done") { (action, indexPath) in
                
                //STEP1: Append the task to the doneTasksArr:
                self.doneTasksArr.append(self.tasksArray[indexPath.row])
                
                //STEP2: Delete the task from the tasksArray since it was done.
                self.context.delete(self.tasksArray[indexPath.row])
                
                //STEP3: Remove the Row:
                self.tasksArray.remove(at: indexPath.row)
                
                //STEP4: Update the Model:
                self.saveTasks()
            }
            
            
            //configure btn:
            doneAction.backgroundColor = .cyan
            
            return [doneAction]
            
        } else {
            let deleteAction = SwipeAction(style: .destructive, title: "Delete") { action, indexPath in
                
                self.context.delete(self.tasksArray[indexPath.row])
                
                self.tasksArray.remove(at: indexPath.row)
                
                
                self.saveTasks()
                
                tableView.reloadData()
            }
            
            return [deleteAction]
        }
        
    }
    
    
    override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
        tableView.deselectRow(at: indexPath, animated: true)
        
        
    }
    
    // MARK: - Class Methods:
    @IBAction func addBtnTapped(_ sender: UIBarButtonItem) {
        
        insertNewTask()

    }
    
    
    
    func insertNewTask() {
        var textField = UITextField()
        
        
        let alert = UIAlertController(title: "New Task", message: "Please Add Your Task", preferredStyle: .alert)
        
        alert.addTextField { (alertTextField) in
            alertTextField.placeholder = "Create New Task"
            textField = alertTextField
        }
        
        
        let action = UIAlertAction(title: "Add", style: .default) { (action) in
            let newItem = Task(context: self.context)
            newItem.title = textField.text!
            
            

            self.tasksArray.append(newItem)
            self.saveTasks()
            self.tableView.reloadData()

        }
        

        alert.addAction(action)
        
        
        
        self.present(alert, animated: true, completion: nil)
        
    }
    
    
    
    // MARK: - Sege Section:
    @IBAction func segeControlTapped(_ sender: UISegmentedControl) {
        
        switch Sege.selectedSegmentIndex {
        case 0:
            rowsToDisply = tasksArray
            
        case 1:
            rowsToDisply = doneTasksArr
            
        default:
            print("There's something wrong with Sege!")
        }
        
        tableView.reloadData()
    }
    




         //MARK: - Model Manipulation Methods:
func saveTasks() {
    do {
        try! context.save()
    } catch {
        print("Error Saving context \(error)")
    }
}

func loadTasks() {
    let request: NSFetchRequest<Task> = Task.fetchRequest()
    do{
        tasksArray = try! context.fetch(request)
    } catch {
        print("There was an error with loading items \(error)")
    }
}

}
```

Comment: This is because you use `rowsToDisply` as your data model but don't update its value when you update `tasksArray`, also where do you define `loadTasks`?

Comment: @NoodleOfDeath didn't copy that before, but now I have added it

Comment: Your approach is pretty cumbersome. A better approach is to use `NSFetchedResultsController` and an extra attribute `isDone` in the `Task` entity. In `segeControlTapped` for case 1 create a predicate to filter the data (`isDone == true`), apply it to the results controller and refetch the data. This is more efficient and less error-prone. Another benefit is that you get nice table view animations.

Comment: @vadian Got ya, will try that! :) btw I need to implement the NSPredicate into the loadTasks()?

Answer (score 0):

Initially, rowsToDisply values are assigned twice. In the beginning and during the segment change. The new task is added on the `tasksArray` but the `rowsToDisply` not updated automatically. You should update the `rowsToDisply` manually.
In add action, you can use

```
self.rowsToDisply.append(newItem)
```

after this line

```
self.tasksArray.append(newItem)
```

And then reload the tableView. Hope this will update the new data on the list.

Comment: Yep it works :) the thing is every time I change the value in the segment to Done, it doesn't show my DoneArray for some reason, even tho I set the rowsToDisply to DoneArray.

Comment: The done tasks should update after changing segment control.

Comment: is the issue is fixed? Mark this answer as accepted if this help to solve your problem.

Comment: yep it is fixed but used something else :) thanks for the help anyway <3

Answer (score 0):

After insertNewTask(), reload the table view or reload the exact row that was updated.